# How to fill angular textbox in a webview2 with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, webview2

I have a webpage wiht a lot of textbox. I can fill textbox with this code:

```
webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('txtPerson_FirstName').value='John';");
```

But this code doesnt work on a textbox. This is textbox source code :

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" name="Quantity_Amount" ng-model="line.Quantity_Amount" ng-keyup="totalCalculator(line,line.AllowanceCalculatorType)" style="width:100%" type="number">
```

How can I fill textbox in C# using webView2. Thanks